# xCode Video player with png overlays

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode

I am new at iOS development. I wish to ask you how if it possible to play video with images overlay. What I`m wishing to do is play some mp4 file, and on top of it put some png file that the user can change (UIimageview on top of video). At android development i used "media view" and could control it any way i wont. Didn't found in xCode similar view.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a look at [MPMoviePlayerController](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/mediaplayer/reference/MPMoviePlayerController_Class/Reference/Reference.html). You can use that's view the same as any other UIView.

Comment: Can I see this view in xib or storyboard file?

Comment: I don't think so, no. You have to create the MoviePlayerController in code and add it's view something like `[self.view addSubview:moviePlayerController.view];`